# Parsing a JSON API response

Tags: json, flutter, dart

An API is giving me a JSON response like so :

```
{
    "amountCredited":0,
    "isFirstOrder":false,
     "orderItems":[
       {
          "_id":624342e1c66be9001d501230,
          "status":2,
          "pinCode":749326,
          "kioskId":61bb3982089a66001db4ab77,
          "kioskActivityId":620668ad433322b99557c874
          }
       ]
}
```

I'm trying to access the data inside the `"orderItems"` in order to feed it to an existing parsing model in the App

```
order = OrderItemModel.fromJson(response.body['orderItems'] as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

but since the data inside `orderItems` JSON response is inside an **array** I can't access it this way..

How can I access it knowing that this JSON `"orderItems"` array will always only have one item as a response ?

---

*Would something like `response.body['orderItems' : [0]]` enable me to access the first item data ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you always know that the array will always have only one item. We'll first make it a List & then access the first element.

```
order = OrderItemModel.fromJson((response.body['orderItems'] as List<dynamic>).first as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

**To understand it a bit better refer to the code below:**

The JSON response contains an array, which we need to access.

```
final ordersArray = response.body['orderItems'] as List<dynamic>;
```

Then we want to access the first order (according to the question)

```
final firstOrder = ordersArray.first as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Once we have the order, we'll convert it to the model

```
final order = OrderItemModel.fromJson(firstOrder);
```

EDIT:
as it was pointed out in a comment List objects have a getter called `first` which can be used to get the first element, the code has been updated with that.

Comment: There is also the convenience object on every `List` called [first](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/first.html). You get the first order like so: `ordersArray.first`.  As opposed to using the 0 index. Both approaches will return the same data.

Comment: I feel like the solution @daddygames offered is better looking, will update my answer with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert as `Map` and `List` because Flutter deal only with this datatypes. For example:

```
Map order1 = {
          "_id":"624342e1c66be9001d501230",
          "status":2,
          "pinCode":749326,
          "kioskId":"61bb3982089a66001db4ab77",
          "kioskActivityId":"620668ad433322b99557c874"
          };
  Map order2 = {
          "_id":"224342e1c66be9001d501232",
          "status":1,
          "pinCode":248023,
          "kioskId":"41bb3982089a66001db4ab74",
          "kioskActivityId":"720668ad433322b99557c875"
          };
  Map m = {
    "amountCredited":0,
    "isFirstOrder":false,
     "orderItems":[
       order1,
       order2
       ]
};
  
  
  print(m['orderItems'][1]);
  print(m['orderItems'][1]['pinCode']);
```

The result will be:

```
 {_id: 224342e1c66be9001d501232, status: 1, pinCode: 248023, kioskId: 41bb3982089a66001db4ab74, kioskActivityId: 720668ad433322b99557c875}
248023
```